# Import file using C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am currently programming in C#, and i have created a new file in my solution directory. just wondering, is there any way i can import the new file into my solution using C# coding? if it can't be done, any suggestion on how i can do it in a simple manner that even novice user can do it without a fuss?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: have you googled it? there are plenty of tutorials out there. come here when you have a specific problem or question.

Comment: Right click on the folder it is in in the solution panel and select 'Add Existing'

Comment: Assuming you are using Visual Studio...what is complicated about right-clicking and choosing `Add Existing Item...`.

Comment: @MotoSV obvs that is fine for experts, but what about _novices_ ;)

Comment: I think it would be more complicated and long-winded for a novice to use some custom implementation for adding files to a solution. If a novice cannot perform a simple operation like "Add Existing Item..." they will probably struggle with the rest of Visual Studio.

Comment: dont get me wrong @DLeh. i do know how to import file into my solution, however my question is how to do it using coding. and yes i have googled, all the tutorials are only on how to import manually and not through using c# codes

Comment: @MotoSV yes i agree with u, just wondering if i can come up with a better way. thank you anyway

Comment: Why would you need to have it done via C# coding? What would happen when you have changes pending to your solution and your automatic coding overrides your solution file?

Comment: @BerndLinde that is because what i am trying to do here, is to write a new file using c# code and directly import it in. and i have already done the creation of new file. therefore, wondering if there is a way to code so as to import the file directly.

Comment: @Dleh this is the top result on Google now

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes: you can use C# code to modify the project file to include the new file (either by editing the XML directly, or maybe there's a Visual Studio API that will let you add it). Note that this won't automatically make the code you're running include the new code, since it must be compiled first, etc.

In practice, what you should do is simply add it in Visual Studio: right click on the project > Add > Existing Item... or, click the "Show All Files" button in the Solution Explorer, and then right click on the new file (assuming you placed it in the project) > Include in Project.

Comment: thank u @Tim S. editing the xml can be quite risky, chances of ruining the whole project file exist. i guess, i just have to do up a message box to ask the user to import manually. at the same time, i will try to search for any api to do so if there is any.